# add layers in Google Earth Engine without mask

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to add several layers in Google Earth Engine. Everything works fine except some layers have masks and the resulting image does include masked regions. I need masked regions to contain a value of 1.

```
var threat2 = presz.add(slopeii.add(zonesZ.add(changeZ.add(lossZ))));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your full code / workflow.

Comment: Sorry, but your link doesn't help very much. The variables you use in your post above don't even exist in the code ...

Comment: I'm sorry. This is the correct link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/27c7f12487911f428ed33ed3cac0ce8b

Comment: I have found my error but still can't fix it. One layer, changeZ, contains NAN values. I know how to replace it in R but not in GEE.

Comment: I've noticed the scaling didn't work as expected, as the values aren't clamped. Can you try `var changeZ = change.unitScale(-50,50).clamp(0, 1).multiply(4).add(1)` instead? Besides that, it's difficult to help, such a big script with a lot of mapping is confusing. If the problem still persists, can you remove unnecessary parts and explain a bit more detailed where the problem occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unmask all masked pixels and assign a value of 1 for each of them, just use the unmask method of ee.Image.

Assume my_image is the image with mask.

```
unmasked_image = my_image.unmask(1);
```